Stark Effect for the multiplet $n = 2$ (Gottfried, problem 12, chapter 5, 2nd ed.)
I am trying to solve this problem, specially part $(a)$, which says the following:
This problem concerns the Stark effect in the $n = 2$ multiplet of hydrogen. Because the Lamb shift is small compared to the fs splitting, the spectrum as a function of field strength has several interesting features.
(a) Calculate the matrix elements of $eEz$ in the basis that diagonalizes $H_{fs}$. Show that
the $|m|= 3/2$ states are unaffected, whereas the perturbed energies and eigenstates in the
space of the $|m|$ = 1/2 states can found by diagonalizing.
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
0 & \sqrt{3}\epsilon & 0 \\
\sqrt{3}\epsilon & \Delta_1 & -\sqrt{6}\epsilon \\
0 & -\sqrt{6}\epsilon & \Delta_2 
\end{pmatrix} = H  $$
where
$$\epsilon = eEa_0, \  \Delta_1 = E(s_{1/2})- E(p_{1/2}) , \  \Delta_2  = E(p_{3/2})- E(p_{1/2}) . $$
For $n = 2$ we have the states $2s_{1/2}, 2p_{1/2}, 2p_{3/2}, $. Using the basis $\left| n  l m    \right\rangle$ we have the basis elements: $$\left| 2 \ 0 \ 0   \right\rangle,  \left| 2 \ 1 \ -1   \right\rangle, \left| 2 \ 1 \ 0   \right\rangle, \left| 2 \ 1 \ 1   \right\rangle  .$$ Since we have to use the basis that diagonalizes $H_{fs}$ we have to include the spin configurations $\pm \frac{1}{2}$ Which would double the number of basis elements. We can forget about the $n$ index since it's two for every element. I don't Understand how I would end up with that $3 \times 3$ matrix for the perturbation. Does the selection rule $\Delta l = 0 $ apply for this case? as in the linear Stark effect.  I am guessing that symmetries and selection rules make most of the matrix elements to vanish and the problem reduces to this matrix, but I don't see how to show the $m$ selection rule. I'd really appreciate any guidance.

Hint: the $\vert m \vert=3/2$ states come only from the $\vert m_\ell\vert=1$ states and thus contain no $\ell=0$ states in the coupled basis. On the other hand the $m=\pm 1/2$ have parents with $m_\ell=\pm 1$ and $m_\ell=0$.


(a) Calculate the matrix elements of $eEz$ in the basis that diagonalizes $H_{fs}$. Show that
the $|m|= 3/2$ states are unaffected,


whereas the perturbed energies and eigenstates in the
space of the $|m|$ = 1/2 states can found by diagonalizing...


For $n = 2$ we have the states $2s_{1/2}, 2p_{1/2}, 2p_{3/2}, $.

Yes. There are eight states of interest.

We can forget about the $n$ index since it's two for every element.

In general the radial wavefunction can depend on both $n$ and $\ell$, so if you are doing precise numerical calculations you have to keep track. But, for our purposes, we can ignore those difference.

I don't Understand how I would end up with that $3 \times 3$ matrix for the perturbation. Does the selection rule $\Delta l = 0 $ apply for this case?

No. The selection rule is $\Delta \ell = \pm 1$ and $\Delta m_\ell = 0$, since we are interested in matrix elements of $z$.

I am guessing that symmetries and selection rules make most of the matrix elements to vanish and the problem reduces to this matrix, but I don't see how to show the $m$ selection rule.

In this case, the $m$ selection rule is also $\Delta m=0$ just like the $m_\ell$ selection rule.

I'd really appreciate any guidance.

I seems like you are supposed to be working in the $|j, m; \ell, s\rangle$ basis, if that is the basis that "diagonalizes $H_{fs}$." (But you haven't said what $H_{fs}$ is.)
In that case, you might want to use Clebsch-Gordan coefficients to rewrite the $|j,m\rangle$ states in terms of $|\ell, m_\ell\rangle|1/2, m_s\rangle$ states so it is easier to see the selection rules for your $z$ matrix.
For example
$$
|3/2, 3/2\rangle = |1,1\rangle|\uparrow\rangle\;,\tag{1}
$$
where $|\uparrow\rangle$ is shorthand for $|1/2, 1/2\rangle$.
As, you can see, the $|3/2,3/2\rangle$ state is the "stretch state" and has $\ell=m_\ell=1$ and $s=m_s=1/2$. Because it has $\ell=1$ it has no matrix elements with any other of the six p-based states (by the $\Delta \ell =\pm 1$ selection rule). Because it has $m_\ell=1$ it has no matrix elements with any of the two s-based states (by the $\Delta m_\ell =0$ selection rule).
As another example
$$
|3/2, 1/2\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|11\rangle|\downarrow\rangle + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}|10\rangle|\uparrow\rangle\;,
$$
which, again, has no matrix elements with any of the six p-based states. But this state can have a matrix element with one of the s-based states:
$$
\langle j=1/2, m=1/2; \ell=0, s=1/2| eE\hat z | j=3/2, m=1/2; \ell=1, s=1/2\rangle
$$
$$
=eE\langle 0,0|\langle \uparrow| \hat z \left(
\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|11\rangle|\downarrow\rangle + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}|10\rangle|\uparrow\rangle
\right)
$$
$$
=eE\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}\langle 0,0|\hat z |10\rangle
$$
$$
=eE\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}\int dr r^2 R_{2s}(r) r R_{2p}(r)
\int d\Omega Y_{00}(\Omega)\sqrt{\frac{4\pi}{3}}Y_{10}(\Omega) Y_{10}(\Omega)
$$
$$
=eE\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\int dr r^3 R_{2s}(r) R_{2p}(r)
$$
